# mysql query (join) and adding subqueries

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I've this query, and it displays results correctly. I didn't use join, but it still seems to return correct values, how is that possible?

```
SELECT connections.id,
       connections.word_id,
       connections.order_id,
       connections.top,
       connections.deleted,
       (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(connections.modified)) AS modified_ago,
       words_en.word,
       (CASE WHEN words_en.user_id = 1 THEN "You" ELSE words_en.user_id END) AS created_by
FROM connections, words_en
WHERE connections.word_id = words_en.id AND connections.user_id = 1
IN (SELECT COUNT(*) connections WHERE /* Result of previous select connections.word_id */ AND connections.user_id != 1)
ORDER BY connections.order_id
```

1. Is it enough to do this: `connections.word_id = words_en.id` to join?
2. I would also like to add sub-queries to this. What is syntax for that?

sub-query should count number of times `conenctions.word_id` appears in connections table where `connections.user_id != 1` ergo how many times other users used this word.

1. I also need another join that would get me `users.name_surname` for `words_en.user_id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To join tables we can use ,(Comma) or join keyword.
If we are using ,(Comma) it will give exact result as per our condition. 
If we are using join keyword we can use many types of join like left join right join , and many more. These all joins will give different result.

We can say ,(Comma) join is same as JOIN but not as LEFT JOIN.

Below is the example to write sub query

```
SELECT connections.id,
       connections.word_id,
       connections.order_id,
       connections.top,
       connections.deleted,
       (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(connections.modified)) AS modified_ago,
       words_en.word,
       words_en.user_id 
FROM connections, words_en
WHERE connections.word_id = words_en.id AND connections.user_id IN (select id from connections)
ORDER BY connections.order_id
```

`select id from connections` is subquery

For your 3rd point try below

```
SELECT users.name_surname 
FROM users, words_en
WHERE users.user_id = words_en.user_id
ORDER BY users.user_id
```

Comment: remove the ';' inside the second select

Comment: Yes, but I need to incorporate 3rd point in the original query... this is what I don't get how to do :)

Comment: use above ans as example add conditions after where clause for conditions and select fields those you want to display.

Comment: yes but I don't want simply to display. But count based on results of previous select...

Comment: You can use "count(column_name) as my_alias_name" in your select clause. If you want to count based on condition, google about using "CASE...WHEN MySQL".

Answer (score 0):

for a join -operation:

```
SELECT connections.id,
   connections.word_id,
   connections.order_id,
   connections.top,
   connections.deleted,
   (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(connections.modified)) AS modified_ago,
   words_en.word,
   words_en.user_id 
FROM connections
LEFT JOIN  words_en ON connections.word_id = words_en.id AND connections.user_id = 1
WHERE 
     words_en.id IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY connections.order_id
```

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LEFT JOIN words_en ON connections.word_id = words_en.id AND connections.user_id ' at line 10

Comment: There's a trailing comma after `FROM connections`.